# Issue with MVC4 applications logo

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I am trying to include a logo to my MVC 4 site. Upon clicking on that logo, it should navigate  to the home screen. I am using the following piece of code in the **_Layout.cshtml** file to achieve this.

```
<a href='<%= Url.Action("Index","Home") %>'> <img src="../Images/logo.JPG" /></a>
```

In internet explorer, if I click on the logo, nothing seems to be happening. But in Google Chrome, I am getting the error as *Bad Request - Invalid URL* . The URL content is

```
http://localhost:3347/Home/%3C%=%20Url.Action(%22Index%22,%22Home%22)%20%%3E
```

Please let me know if I am making any mistake here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

`<a href='@Url.Action("Index","Home")'> <img src="../Images/logo.JPG" /></a>`

or you can use

`<a href='/'> <img src="../Images/logo.JPG" /></a>`

If the root of your site is '/' i.e. it still ends up going to Home/Index anyway, if that's the default configured in `RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes()`.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that it's literally setting the link to `<%= Url.Action("Index","Home") %>`, *not* the results of that call. Razor templates don't use the `<%= %>` syntax. Try the following instead:

```
<a href='@Url.Action("Index","Home")'> <img src="../Images/logo.JPG" /></a>
```

Also, when dealing with static assets, you should use `Url.Content`, which will prefix the correct application path for you so you don't end up breaking links in various deployment scenarios:

```
<img src="@Url.Content("~/Images/logo.jpg")" />
```